# Labelling the surrounding of a 2D array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created a 2D array that was filled dynamically with contents. the array size is also dynamic. I have done the filling dynamically including the size. Doing the labels surrounding my current array is what I'm having trouble with.

my code for 2d array:

```
        string** cityArray = new string*[rowCount];

        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
            cityArray[i] = new string[colCount];

        bool found = false;

        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<colCount; j++){
                for(int k=0; k<cityLineSize; k++){
                    if((arrayOfCities[k].gridY == i) && (arrayOfCities[k].gridX == j)){
                        cityArray[i][j] = arrayOfCities[k].cityId + " ";
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!found){
                    cityArray[i][j] = "0 ";
                }
                found = false;
            }
        }

        //reverse
        reverse(&cityArray[0], &cityArray[9]);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i){
            for (int j = 0; j < colCount; ++j){
                cout << cityArray[i][j] << "   ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
```

this is my current 2D array

[image: before label]

Here is what i want to achieve
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to print a line of "#" and similar things for decorating your output? Are you able to output your array (without the problematic lables)? Please show a [mre] of that. For that I think you can reduce the shown code to the last 6 lines, preceeded by a hardcoded array init, wrapped in a compilable `main()`.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes. I could hard code it but I need it to be dynamic as the rows and cols could change. and yes i could output my current array without any error.

Comment: You did not get the point of making a [mre]. I was only recommending on how to do that. When you did that and provided it here then you will (more likely and more quickly) find help.

Comment: And please answer my question whether adding decoration "#" is all you are asking about. Do you need the blue thing? Do you need the coordinate numbers? Apart from the blue, do you need anything special for the non-zero islands? Do you need the zeros replaced by blanks? You question is not clear about that, because it does not specify what you mean by "labels".

Comment: do you want the `#` be elements of the array or only printed? If it is the latter then the way you allocate the array isnt that relevant. Though, you should probably use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>` instead of doing it all manually

Comment: Did you ever follow an exercise like creating patterns in output? Among the first exercises of most classes is "make half a pyramid", "make a pyramid", "make a rectangle". If you did those, redo them, it will get you closer to making the decoration here.